# How to create a new collection on document creation if one doesn't exist (Firebase 9 & NextJS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Basically I am wanting to create a new collection on a document creation if that said collection does not exist.

Here is the structure I have

-Company (Collection)

--Company Name (Doc)

---CompanyInfo (Doc)

---Users (Collection)

----Users (Docs)

This is working if I create the collection manually in firebase, but I want these to somehow create automatically when a company signs up

Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/JeCAM3Fx

```
const handleCreate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userInfo) => {
            setDoc(doc(db, `company/${company}/users`, userInfo.uid), {
                firstName,
                lastName,
                email,
                phone,
                address,
                country,
                state,
                company,
                position,
            });
            console.log("You are registerd!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
};
```

I get the error cannot find indexOf() when trying to signup

I am using NextJS and Firebase 9

Comment: Collections are automatically created when you write the first document to them, and automatically deletes when you delete the last document from them. Can you edit the question to include  the copy/pasted exact, complete error message and stack trace that you get?

Comment: This is the exact error I am getting: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')